# Access Stock Control DB with VBA, how to track orders out

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

Good Day All, I need some assistance please. I am working on a stock control DB in access for a small company that manages about 500 products for projects that they are busy with. Now I have the basic structures, the forms, the projects, the products and most of the layouts, queries and formatting done. The majority of the heavy lifting between all these items are, as usual, handled by forms and events with VBA. I now have a bit of a problem that I need to sort out.

All products as ordered are ordered into different batches. So a product today would be ordered in and lands in Batch 25. If another order goes through for the same product then it has to go to batch 26. This is actually done to compensate for pricing changes.

Capturing it in is very easy. But getting it out is a catch.

In one of my forms, the one that allocates the stock, I have;

> Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblInStock Where [ProductCode]='" & Me.Product & "';")

Once the recordset is opened I use the normal "With rs" clause to start going through the records.

I am still learning vba coding, so this will look horrible;

```
With rs
    .MoveFirst
    Do While Not .EOF
        If !Quantity = 0 Then
            .Edit
            .Delete
            .Update
        End If
        If txtQtyTotal.Value - Me.Quantity < 0 Then
            MsgBox "You do not have enough stock to process this request."
            Exit Sub
        End If
        iDeduct = Me.Quantity - txtQtyTotal
        If iDeduct < !Quantity Then
            .Edit
            !Quantity = -iDeduct
            .Update
            .MoveNext
            txtQtyTotal.Value = txtQtyTotal - Me.Quantity
        End If
        If rs.EOF Then Exit Sub
        .Edit
        If -iDeduct <= 0 Then
            iDeduct = 0
        End If
        !Quantity = -iDeduct
        .Update
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With
Set rs = Nothing
```

The thing is that it needs to deduct stock from each of the batches in sequence. This seems to do it 'perfectly well' at the moment but it is only half the battle. The table it moves it to, tblStockOut, has to keep track of the pricing as well as the batches as well.

This means that if I have a total of 50 items from one product, and 10 are in Batch 8 @ $ 15.00 per item, 25 are in Batch 11 @ $16.25 per item and 15 are in Batch 18 @ $15.75 per item, if 30 items are assigned to a project it should:

- Take the 10 items from Batch 8 @ 15.00
- Empty and delete the batch since no products are left in batch 8 anymore
- Take 20 items from Batch 11 @ $16.25 to fill the order.

The above code handles the quantities, still has bugs in it though, but how do I get it to keep track as well of:

- Which batches where used to fill the order
- Cost prices between batches for items

The company wants a report at the end of the day for costing purposes, and obviously they need the different batches' values to be used for the final costing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Argh, I see I copied from the wrong version of the database. Anyway, the code snippet above in the correct one was changed and is working. I just need to add the batch tracking and costing. Thanks

Comment: Just a side note: Shouldn't this condition `If txtQtyTotal.Value - Me.Quantity < 0 Then` be `If txtQtyTotal.Value - Me.Quantity =< 0 Then` ? let me know if I am wrong.